# Knex returns DATETIME fields applying offset of my machine timezone

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have following row saved in timezone `Europe/Madrid` at database:

```
dateA = '2019-03-26 15:00:00'
dateB = '2019-03-26 14:00:00'
```

When selecting the entry:

```
let entry = this.query().findById(id)
```

I get following values (`console.log(entry)`):

```
{ 
  dateA: 2019-03-26T06:00:00.000Z,
  dateB: 2019-03-26T05:00:00.000Z 
}
```

What is applying this convertion?

**My enviroment:**

- Im using knex, objection and moment
- Moment is configured with `moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Madrid')`
- My local machine timezone is set to `UTC+09:00` (Chita) for testing

**I tried:**

Setting a connection timezone on knex creation:

```
const connection = {
  user: dbCreds.username,
  password: dbCreds.password,
  host: hostname,
  database: dbCreds.database,
  timezone: '-1:00'
}
const pool = knex({
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection,
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 30
  }
})
```

I still get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out whats going on.

Knex, when retrieving the info of the datetime field checks the timezone of the database. You can check it using:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

This returns `SYSTEM SYSTEM` in my case. So its using my machine timezone. To test it, I changed it to `UTC`.

So now, when reading the following value:

```
dateA = '2019-03-26 15:00:00'
dateB = '2019-03-26 14:00:00'
```

Knex assumes its in UTC, so the value in UTC is returned:

```
{ 
  dateA: 2019-03-26T15:00:00.000Z,
  dateB: 2019-03-26T14:00:00.000Z 
}
```

Seems not possible to configure MySQL to use `'Europe/Madrid'` as default timezone.